# Guidance creating Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am developing a website which will host different tests on any subject.
I am using nested forms for referencing.
An exam has questions and a question has 4 options and every question has correct answers.
the models are like this:

```
    class Exam < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :questions
     validates :name, presence: true
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, 
     reject_if: proc     {|attributes| attributes['content'].blank?},
                              allow_destroy: true
    end

    class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :exam
     has_many :correct_answers
     validates :content, presence: true
     has_many :options
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :options, 
     reject_if: proc        {|attributes| attributes['content'].blank?},
                              allow_destroy: true
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :correct_answers, reject_if: proc   {|attributes| attributes['content'].blank?},
                              allow_destroy: true                               
     end

    class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :question
    end
```

Now i am not able to understand how to create a web form which can submit the results and can compare the selected choice with correct answer, then render the view with correct answer and selected answers.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use something simple like:

```
<%= form_for(@exam) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <%= f.label :question %>
    <%= f.text_field :question%>
    <%= f.submit Submit %>
```

FYI just read this article if you need any further help with your form 
-> https://www.launchacademy.com/codecabulary/learn-rails/writing-forms

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, this way the parameters of exam model will be submitted. I wish to display the contents of exam ( questions and options), them submit the same. After that i  will compare the marked answer to the correct answer model.